# How to generate 6 points on the perimeter of the circle with mathemathica?

Tags: geometry, wolfram-mathematica, points, mathematica-8

How to generate 6 points on the perimeter of the circle with mathemathica? The points should not be equally distributed. Thank you very much

Comment: Mathematical experts can answer your question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Table[{t=RandomReal[{0,2Pi}];Cos[t],Sin[t]},{6}]
```

or are you trying to display those like this?

```
Graphics[Point[Table[{t=RandomReal[{0,2Pi}];Cos[t],Sin[t]},{6}]]]
```

or

```
points=Table[p=RandomReal[{0,2Pi}];{Cos[p],Sin[p]},{6}];
Print[points]
ParametricPlot[{Cos[phi],Sin[phi]},{phi,0,2Pi},
  Epilog->{PointSize[Large],Map[Point,points]}]
```

Comment: Thank you. The second version looks like what i need. But they would have to be on a circle. I dont know how can I see the coordinates of those points